# Imagem jsf java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou querendo colocar um imagem em uma página JSF, netbeans, mas a página não apresenta a imagem.

Eu estou chamando a imagem no meu código assim:

```
<h:graphicImage library="resources/imagens" name="LojaRoupas.jpg"/>
```

Minha estrutura do projeto está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, tenta retirar suas páginas xhtml da pasta WEB-INF.

Comment: eu tirei as paginas da WEB-Inf mas continua o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retire suas paginas da pasta `WEB-INF`. Deixe-as dentro da página `Paginas Web`.

Considerando que o arquivo `LojaRoupas.jpg` está dentro da pasta `imagens`: no atributo `library` retire a pasta `resources`. A pasta `resources` serve exatamente pra informar que o que vem abaixo são `libraries`.

Deixe assim: `library="imagens"`.

Comment: Eu arrumei minha estrutura do projeto como vc disse mais continua o mesmo erro

Comment: Alterou o conteúdo do atributo `library` também?

Answer (score 1):

cria um diretório imagens dentro de resources em WEB-INF e coloca sua imagem la dentro. deixa seu código assim

```
<h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="LojaRoupas.jpg"/>
```

Lembre-se o param library já procura direto no diretório resources